# Why is my clearly-worded, on-topic Windows-10 configuration-related question being downvoted and marked for closure?

Tags: support

First it was downvoted for no apparent reason, then two votes for closure were added on the basis of the question being unclear. Then another vote-to-close was made on the basis of it being off topic. Am I missing something here? Is the site being moderated by people who don't speak English or have enough courtesy to at least comment on the question before stomping on it?

[How do I find out which programs have registered global hotkeys in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1091942/how-do-i-find-out-which-programs-have-registered-global-hotkeys-in-windows-10)

The original text, which I later edited for extreme brevity, was:

> Today I booted up my computer, started up WinAmp as my usual first order of business, and then noticed that the media hotkeys weren't working. I closed WinAmp only to be greeted with an error dialog stating that WinAmp had been unable to register my media hotkeys as they were already registered to "another program". I have lots and lots of processes running. How can I find out which programs have poached a given global hotkey? Obviously I tried pressing the hotkeys in question- nothing happened.
>
> I am running Windows 10. Some of the usual solutions require software that does not work correctly in Windows 8+. Rule of thumb; if the site doesn't mention Windows 10 and uses screenshots showing a Windows 7 or Stardock-themed window, then the program probably doesn't work in Windows 10.

Comment: People are free to downvote for whatever reason they like, for example Tim Post [lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) again.

Comment: "To the nasty person who downvoted this question" is at best "not constructive" (since downvotes are anonymous and there is no requirement to explain) and at worst "rude of offensive".

Comment: I have deleted the comment. Note of course that it was a comment, and not part of the question itself. Nevertheless, the entire question must be closed as a result?

Comment: I forget if I voted to close because I thought the question was broad ( you don't mention specifics I feel are required for me to answer the question ) or if I thought the question was unclear ( for pretty much the same reasons ) but your attitude towards down votes is rediculous

Comment: @Ramhound We can agree to disagree on my opinions about downvoting - I see it as a matter of common courtesy - but rather than just voting to close a question, why not recognise that a question is asked when someone is trying to solve a problem and indicate what it is that you think is lacking (via a comment) before punishing the question? Vote to close it if the person doesn't bother to respond or provide the additional details that you think should be there.

Comment: My vote to close is normal my reason for my down vote.....I have learned if I tell people I voted they will just revenge vote my profile on other sites

Comment: @Ramhound, if it's any consolation, this practice of _revenge voting_ is not universal.  I've sometimes scanned profiles of disagreeable commentators, (to "consider the source"), and most often find reasons to *upvote* their other (better) posts, or ignore them.  In light of which, a policy of *preemptive closing* seems like a weaker [iterated prisoner's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma) strategy.

Comment: @agc - It might not be universal but I have still lost hundreds of reputation points on Stackoverflow because of a comment I made to a user on Superuser.  Of course I have asked several times (more then 5 times) to have those targeted questions to be disassoicated from by account the moderators over at Stackoverflow have refused to do so.  So its a victious cycle, I say something about the quality of a question or answer at Superuser, which upsets somebody and because they have reputation at SO they vote every question of mine down.

Comment: @Ramhound, interesting story.  Anyway, I'd say two things.  1) Don't descend to the level of those that do that.  2) People not being invariably dedicated to fair play, perhaps your story indicates a need for a kind of spider software that checks for possible revenge vote system gaming/bullying -- the practice would leave a distinctive electronic footprint.  i.e. there'd be an initial downvote, followed by a cascade of them.   Using SE's internal (secret) database would be ideal, but detecting likely correlation via the public database would be the more challenging programming problem.

Comment: @agc - I don't descend to the level of those that do.  I vote on the content a user submits.  If I believe the question/answer is helpful or not helpful I vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TBH the original question was better. I'd actually add *more* information.

1. What your keyboard is, since some keyboard have special magic configuration software.
2. What the 'usual solutions' that worked in windows 7 or older *that you actually tried* (This solves the 'research' issue).
3. I disagree its off topic, and if I noticed it had been closed, I'd be *inclined* to vote to reopen.